# Reading large PBF file with GDAL

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, command-line

I'm trying to use GDAL to read-in a large .pbf file containing OSM data for London. The problem is that `ogrinfo` returns an error message, `Too many features have accumulated ...` as shown in the reproducible example below, or outputs a file that seems to have no features (or `-1` according to the reproducible example below!):

```
gdalinfo --version
# $ GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28

# get data
wget http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england/greater-london-latest.osm.pbf

ogrinfo -oo OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING=YES *pbf lines > x2
# $ Warning 6: driver OSM does not support open option OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING
# $ ERROR 1: Too many features have accumulated in points layer. Use OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING=YES mode
ogrinfo -oo INTERLEAVED_READING=YES *pbf lines > x3
wc x3
# $  27  65 740 x3 # contains no features
```

A couple of questions:

- Can others reproduce this behaviour and is it expected?
- What command can be used to make GDAL output the full dataset?

See below for the full output of the command, which seems right according to the documentation at https://gdal.org/drv_osm.html :

```
ogrinfo -oo INTERLEAVED_READING=YES *pbf lines
INFO: Open of `greater-london-latest.osm.pbf'

 using driver `OSM' successful.



Layer name: lines
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: -1
Extent: (-0.511482, 51.285540) - (0.335437, 51.693440)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
osm_id: String (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
highway: String (0.0)
waterway: String (0.0)
aerialway: String (0.0)
barrier: String (0.0)
man_made: String (0.0)
z_order: Integer (0.0)
other_tags: String (0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: [solution](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2100) here from Even Rouault:

```
ogrinfo -rl greater-london-latest.osm.pbf lines
```

> Conversion to something else like GeoPackage is the recommended way of using them.

```
ogr2ogr out.gpkg greater-london-latest.osm.pbf lines
```

The first solution works. Not yet got the the 2nd solution to work.

Comment: The 2nd command works for me with GDAL 3.1.0dev. It may be that for older versions the format must be defined `-f gpkg`.